# what are kanji that can be flipped, but not rotated?

Tags: kanji

Plenty of kanji are symmetrical on the y-axis and x-axis. Plenty of kanji are symmetrical only on the y-axis.

What are some kanji that are only symmetrical on the x-axis? I don't know one.

What kanji change into another kanji when they are rotated and/or flipped? Here is one that I know:
 干 -- flip --> 士

Comment: 「曰」. Which is not the same as 「日」. Also, 「人」 is *not* symmetrical, only its gothic form is (its mirror is 「入」).

Comment: Sometimes symmetry depends on how you write them.  I've seen people write 女 in a way that's left-right symmetrical, for example.

Comment: @snailboat:  You mean when it looks like `甘` without the lower horizontal stroke, and strokes barely cross at the bottom right corner?

Comment: @kinyo:  FYI, flipping vertically is not the same rotating 180°.  Those two actions will only produce the same result if the character is symmetric about the vertical axis.  Rotating the letter `N` by 180° will give the same letter, but flipping it vertically will give `и `.

Comment: @istrasci Ah, I saw the near-symmetrical 女 again and I took a picture! http://i.stack.imgur.com/CyTar.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's two that have just horizontal symmetry, at least in some fonts: 旧 咺

Answer (score 0):

巨 臣 排 区 州 唱, etc. but this is for fun only.  Some are not as symetrical as others.